# Mounting a folder from the host to a Docker, while running it as Cromwell runtime

Tags: wdl, workflow-management, docker

I have a pipeline, which is written in `WDL` & runs with the help of `Cromwell`. I use `Docker` for containerization.
However, my container is dependent on huge (>100GB databases), which cannot be shipped with the image.
Is there an option to mount a directory from the host filesystem to a `Docker` while running `Cromwell` workflow? I found this functionality in `snakemake`, therefore I assume it is common, but I haven't found it in the docs yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert of WDL but looking at [Cromwell documentation](https://cromwell.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/Containers/#configuration-in-detail), there is a block in the configuration of `Cromwell` called `submit-docker`:

> you'll need to modify the config block
> inside backend.providers in your Cromwell configuration. In
> particular, this block contains a key called submit-docker

In this [example file](https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell/blob/develop/cromwell.example.backends/cromwell.examples.conf#L420), on line `420`, it is possible to specify the mount option which is `-v /path/you/need/to/mount:/path/in/docker/container` (usually they are the same) to Docker command line. Setting it like that should work.

Comment: Thanks, I modified config and was able to mount directories!